# Are there any triangular square pyramidal numbers? (Except $1$ and $55$)

Tags: number-theory

A friend asked me whether $55$ is the only square pyramidal number that is also a triangular number, and whether there is a proof either way. I couldn't see a way to solve it and would appreciate any thoughts.

Square pyramid number : $ \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $

Triangular number :  $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $

Thank you.

Comment: [OEIS A039596](https://oeis.org/A039596).

Answer (score 3):

The corresponding [MathWorld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquarePyramidalNumber.html) details a method to find numbers which are both triangular and square pyramidal.

An excerpt to make the answer complete:

> It involves solving the Diophantine equation: $$\frac{m(m+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ Completing the square gives us: $$\frac12\left(m +\frac12\right)^2 - \frac18 = \frac16\left(2n^3+3n^2+n\right)$$ $$\implies 3(2m+1)^2 = 8n^3+12n^2+4n+3$$ whose solutions $(n,m)$ correspond to the triangular square pyramidal numbers $$1, 55, 91,  208335$$